# Transfer MySQL data from machineX to machineY

Tags: mysql

I want to collect MySQL data from 10 different machines and aggregate into a one big MySQL db on a different machine. All machines are Linux based.

What is the "mysqldump" syntax if I want to do this periodically to collect only the "delta" data?

Are there any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: Why not use replication instead?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't natively supported in MySQL. You could use replication, but a replica can have only a single master, not 10 masters. I know of two workable options:

1) is to script something up that switches the replica between masters in a round-robin fashion. You might wish to refer to http://code.google.com/p/mysql-mmre/ or http://thenoyes.com/littlenoise/?p=117.

2) is to use an ETL tool.

If you get stuck, we (Percona) can help you. This is a common request, but not an easy one, because each case is different.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump` can't generate incremental backups, as it doesn't have any way of determining which rows (or what parts of the schema!) have changed since the last backup, or indeed even when the last backup was. For that you'd need something which could read the MySQL binlog and convert it into a bunch of `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` statements; I'm not aware of anything that exists quite like that.

The current "state of the art" in MySQL backups is generally considered to be [Percona XtraBackup](http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-xtrabackup%3astart).

Comment: You'd be able to do them using GNU diff/patch.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Master Slave?  Have each of the 10 as Masters, and the aggregate a slave to all 10.  This assumes that the data you are aggregating is different on each of the 10.  If the data is the same (or similar) on all 10 and you want to interleave it as well as integrate it then this won't work.